# How to get the difference between two datetimes in hours and minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

If I have two datetimes like this :

```
transtime_in, transtime_out
```

How to get the difference between those datetimes in the following format :

```
hh:mm
```

---

I use

```
DATEDIFF(hour, transtime_in, transtime_out)
```

but i get the hours only .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @transtime_in DATETIME
    , @transtime_out DATETIME

SELECT 
      @transtime_in = '2013-05-19 08:58:07.000'
    , @transtime_out = '2013-05-19 16:40:53.000'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @transtime_out - @transtime_in, 108), 5)
```

**Output:**

```
-----
07:42
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , could u explain why `108` ?

Comment: Because, if you use CONVERT with 108 format, you will get HH:MM:SS and after it concat to HH:MM by using LEFT. Possibly, it's the simplest way to do this.

Comment: 108 is the style for hh:mm:ss. You can find additional information here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: +1 very nice answer - presented great. The style argument is something I've never fully understood - but do now - even though I've been using it regularly to convert times to DateKeys `CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)`

Comment: Can I ask? why is it, it gives me an error in line varchar(10)?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @D1 datetime
declare @D2 datetime

set @D1 = '2014-03-25 00:00:00.000'
set @D2 = '2014-03-24 17:14:05.000'

--select datediff(hour, cast(@D1 as time(0)), cast(@D2 as time(0)))
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @D2 - @D1, 108), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @D1 datetime
declare @D2 datetime

set @D1 = '2014-03-25 00:00:00.000'
set @D2 = '2014-03-24 17:14:05.000'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @D1 - @D2, 108), 8)
```