# How to sum set of period times in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

If I have result set like that :

```
Work_hour(hh:mm)
10:24
12:59
06:28
```

---

```
where Work_hour is of type varchar
```

---

How to sum those hours and minutes with the same format ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(TMP1.MINS/60) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST((TMP1.MINS % 60) AS VARCHAR) FROM (
    SELECT SUM (CAST(LEFT(time_column, 2) AS INT) * 60 + CAST(RIGHT(time_column, 2) AS INT)) as MINS FROM table1
) AS TMP1
```

Where **time_column** is the column in the table and **table1** is the name of the table. Example:

```
create table table1 (
    time_column varchar(10)
);
insert into table1 (time_column) values ('12:20'), ('10:40'), ('15:50');
```

Results in: **38:50**

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT b.Sch_Name
,a.day_flag vac
,c.modified
, CAST(FLOOR(TMP1.MINS/60) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST((TMP1.MINS % 60) AS VARCHAR) FROM (
    SELECT SUM (CAST(LEFT(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in, 108), 5), 2) AS INT) * 60 + CAST(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in, 108), 5), 2) AS INT)) as MINS FROM [dbo].[overtime_calc] a 
)AS TMP1
FROM [dbo].[calc] a INNER JOIN   [dbo].[Sch] b
ON a.sch_id = b.Sch_ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHECK] c`

Comment: `ON a.userid = c.USERID
WHERE a.emp_num = 3266
AND a.trans_date between'2013-05-14' AND '2013-05-18'
GROUP BY a.day_flag,b.Sch_Name,c.modified`

I get error near `From`

Comment: Could you create an SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) demo from your schema with some example data to work on? I see now, what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      work_hour CHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (work_hour)
VALUES 
    ('10:24'),
    ('12:59'),
    ('06:28')

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT mn = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', CAST('19000101 ' + work_hour AS DATETIME)))
    FROM @temp
)
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(mn / 60) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':' + CAST(mn % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))
FROM cte
```

**Output:**

```
hm
--------
29:51
```

**Update 2:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      transtime_out DATETIME
    , transtime_in DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (transtime_out, transtime_in)
VALUES 
    ('2013-05-19 16:40:53.000', '2013-05-19 08:58:07.000'), 
    ('2013-05-19 16:40:53.000', '2013-05-19 08:58:07.000')

SELECT diff = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SUM(CAST(a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 108), 5)
FROM @temp a
```

Comment: `SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', CAST('19000101 ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in, 108), 5) AS DATETIME)))`

return `564165`

Comment: i write the whole query @heikkim ,i try to get the sum of (difference between two fields) like u explain in the previous question but in vain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645641/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-hours-and-minutes

Comment: Is this true :

`CAST(FLOOR(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', CAST('19000101 ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in, 108), 5) AS DATETIME))) / 60) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', CAST('19000101 ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.transtime_out - a.transtime_in, 108), 5) AS DATETIME)))  % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))`

Comment: I get `03:03` and this 's wrong  my data like this :
trans_in :::
`2013-05-14 10:23:18.000
2013-05-15 08:19:32.000
2013-05-16 08:53:29.000`

Comment: trans_out:::
`2013-05-14 20:47:20.000
2013-05-15 21:19:20.000
2013-05-16 15:22:14.000`