# PHP adding multiple datetime to get a total

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Im working with php and mysql, I have a database with two start/stop columns. I want to first get the difference between them.

1. start + stop, which i have

   ```
   $start = new DateTime($start_time);
   $stop = new DateTime($stop_time);
   $difference = $start->diff($stop);
   ```
2. get the total after all the rows have been added up to the format of (H:i:s)

E.G

1. 4 minutes
2. 15 minutes
3. 1 hr
4. etc

========
Total 1:19:00

Comment: You can do all that in the query that selects the data in the first place

Comment: In mysql e.g {select datediff(start_time, stop_time) or timediff(start_time_stop_time)}... I would if i knew more..seems like something that can be done in mysql itself...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645641/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-hours-and-minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two datetimes in hours and minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645641/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-hours-and-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

First declare some totaling variables,

```
$total_hours = 0;
$total_minutes = 0;
$total_seconds = 0;
```

and then loop through each row from your database doing

```
$start = new DateTime($start_time);
$stop = new DateTime($stop_time);
$difference = $start->diff($stop);
echo $difference->h.":".$difference->i.":".$difference->s;
$total_hours += $difference->h;
$total_minutes += $difference->i;
$total_seconds += $difference->s;
```

and finally print the total after the loop

```
echo "========";
echo "Total ".$total_hours.":".$total_minutes.":".$total_seconds;
```

Comment: Yes thanks that works great...I had previously tried something like that but was missing something..

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @FabianGlace Don't forget to accept the answer & upvote so other people will know it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes i upvoted.. One issue that I thought of at first but have confirmed now is the format. in the case where I would get e.g 6 min 141 sec past 60 should be added to the min but how could this be done automatically..I would have to manual to this..